# primefaces chart browser hang

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I want to create liner chart with 68000 point .
actually chart created without any problem and updated every second dynamically .

this is example xhtml file :

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:form id="statistics-form">
        <p:dialog header="Statistics"
                  id="statistics"
                  onHide="closeDialog('side-menu-form:sm-statistics');"
                  widgetVar="statistics"
                  width="700" height="auto"
                  showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade"
                  resizable="false">
            <div class="dialog-content">
                <p:tabView>
                    <p:tab title="System">
                        <p:accordionPanel>
                            <p:tab title="Memory">
                                <h:panelGrid cellpadding="10">
                                    <p:poll interval="1"
                                            global="false"
                                            update="chartMemory"
                                            listener="#{memoryChartBean.init}"/>
                                    <p:chart type="line"
                                             model="#{memoryChartBean.lineModel}"
                                             id="chartMemory"
                                             style="height:210px;width:600px;"/>
                                </h:panelGrid>
                            </p:tab>
                            <p:tab title="Cpu">
                                <h:panelGrid cellpadding="10">
                                    <p:poll interval="1"
                                            global="false"
                                            update="chartCpu"
                                            listener="#{cpuChartBean.init}"/>
                                    <p:chart type="line"
                                             model="#{cpuChartBean.lineModel}"
                                             id="chartCpu"
                                             style="height:190px;width:600px;"/>

                                    <p:poll interval="1" global="false" update="chartLoadAvg"
                                            listener="#{loadAvgChartBean.init}"/>
                                    <p:chart type="line"
                                             model="#{loadAvgChartBean.lineModel}"
                                             widgetVar="chart"
                                             id="chartLoadAvg"
                                             style="height:190px;width:600px;"/>
                                </h:panelGrid>
                            </p:tab>
                        </p:accordionPanel>
                    </p:tab>
                </p:tabView>
            </div>
        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadAvgChartExtender() {
            this.cfg.shadow = false;
            this.cfg.title = 'Load Average';
            this.cfg.seriesColors = ['#003eff', '#7d9800', '#5bab77'];
            this.cfg.grid = {
                background: '#ffffff',
                borderColor: '#ffffff',
                gridLineColor: '#e8e8e8',
                shadow: false
            };
            this.cfg.legend = {
                show: true,
                position: 'sw'
            };
            this.cfg.axesDefaults = {
                borderWidth: 0.1,
                borderColor: '#bdbdbd',
                tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                tickOptions: {
                    fontSize: '8pt'
                }
            };
            this.cfg.seriesDefaults = {
                shadow: false,
                lineWidth: 0.7,
                smooth: true,
                markerOptions: {
                    shadow: false,
                    size: 1
                }
            };
            this.cfg.series = [
                {
                    label: '1 minute'
                },
                {
                    label: '5 minute'
                },
                {
                    label: '15 minute'
                }
            ];
            this.cfg.axes = {
                yaxis: {
                    pad: 0,
                    min: 0,
                    numberTicks: 11,
                    tickOptions: {
                        formatString: "%d"
                    }
                },
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                    tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                    autoscale: true,
                    min: this.cfg.axes.xaxis.min,
                    max: this.cfg.axes.xaxis.max,
                    numberTicks: 24,
                    tickOptions: {
                        angle: 70,
                        showGridline: false,
                        formatString: '%H:%M:%S'
                    }
                }
            };


        }

        function cpuChartExtender() {
            this.cfg.shadow = false;
            this.cfg.title = 'CPU Statistics';
            this.cfg.seriesColors = ['#97cd96', '#000000', '#807990', '#003eff'];
            this.cfg.grid = {
                background: '#ffffff',
                borderColor: '#ffffff',
                gridLineColor: '#e8e8e8',
                shadow: false
            };
            this.cfg.legend = {
                show: true,
                position: 'sw'
            };
            this.cfg.axesDefaults = {
                borderWidth: 0.1,
                borderColor: '#bdbdbd',
                tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                tickOptions: {
                    fontSize: '8pt'
                }
            };
            this.cfg.seriesDefaults = {
                shadow: false,
                lineWidth: 0.3,
                smooth: true,
                markerOptions: {
                    shadow: false,
                    size: 1
                }
            };
            this.cfg.series = [
                {
                    fill: true,
                    label: 'User'
                },
                {
                    label: 'System'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Idle'
                }
            ];
            this.cfg.axes = {
                yaxis: {
                    pad: 0,
                    min: 0,
                    max: 100,
                    numberTicks: 11,
                    tickOptions: {
                        formatString: "%d"
                    }
                },
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                    tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                    autoscale: true,
                    min: this.cfg.axes.xaxis.min,
                    max: this.cfg.axes.xaxis.max,
                    numberTicks: 24,
                    tickOptions: {
                        angle: 70,
                        showGridline: false,
                        formatString: '%H:%M:%S'
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function memoryChartExtender() {
            this.cfg.shadow = false;
            this.cfg.title = 'Memory and Swap Usage';
            this.cfg.seriesColors = ['#807990', '#ff9c59', '#ff9c59', '#000000'];
            this.cfg.grid = {
                background: '#ffffff',
                borderColor: '#ffffff',
                gridLineColor: '#e8e8e8',
                shadow: false
            };
            this.cfg.legend = {
                show: true,
                position: 'sw'
            };
            this.cfg.axesDefaults = {
                borderWidth: 0.1,
                borderColor: '#bdbdbd',
                tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                tickOptions: {
                    fontSize: '8pt'
                }
            };
            this.cfg.seriesDefaults = {
                shadow: false,
                lineWidth: 1,
                smooth: true,
                markerOptions: {
                    shadow: false,
                    size: 1
                }
            };
            this.cfg.series = [
                {
                    fill: true,
                    label: 'Memory Usage'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Swap Usage'
                }
            ];
            this.cfg.axes = {
                yaxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: this.cfg.axes.yaxis.max,
                    numberTicks: 10
                },
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                    tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                    autoscale: true,
                    min: this.cfg.axes.xaxis.min,
                    max: this.cfg.axes.xaxis.max,
                    numberTicks: 24,
                    tickOptions: {
                        angle: 70,
                        showGridline: false,
                        formatString: '%H:%M:%S'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</ui:composition>
```

my problem is browser will hang after about 7 minute when i change tab on accordion panel .
I compare this number of points with echarts or highchart , that libraries has not this problem but primefaces use jqplot and this javascript library can not handle that !(maybe problem is another things)
*(Sorry for bad english)*
What is problem ?
How can fix that ?

Comment: I believe its a known issue that has no resolution yet. Can you check if this is your issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1912

Comment: Wow , poll operation has problem ! , grate man .

Comment: I think its a combo of polling refreshing the whole chart and the chart not being destroyed properly.   We have never chased it further that that as we are calling. I posted a solution below you can try...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try destroying the chart in your poller before it makes its ajax call.

Make sure to give your chart a widgetVar like widgetVar="chartCpuWidget"

```
 <p:poll interval="1"
         global="false"
         update="chartCpu"
         onstart="PF('chartCpuWidget').destroy();"
         listener="#{cpuChartBean.init}"/>
```

Comment: Chart is now flickering and memory increase is still going on... Any idea??

Comment: Hmm others reported that works.  You could try the new ChartsJS charts which replace these legacy jqPlot charts in PrimeFaces 7.0.

Comment: Im using PrimeFaces 7.0

Comment: OK switch to use the new Charts then... https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chartjs/bar/bar.xhtml  See if that fixes your issue.

Comment: Memory is still increasing

Comment: Then I think you have a different issue with something you may be doing? Use this test project and create a small reproducible sample for me to test.  https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test

Comment: After few days of testing I can say that it works fine... is there something similar to the h:outputText??

Comment: What do you mean something similar for h:outputText?  Are you seeing a memory leak in h:outputText?

Comment: Jep... <p:poll interval="10" update="test" /> and <h:outputText id="test" value="#{dashboardMB.sth}" /> increase my memory... at first I though the charts are the problem but now I know it is the outputText. Is there something to clean them or destroy?

Comment: H:outputText is provided by your JSF Impl not by PrimeFaces.  So I don't know.

Comment: Yeah thanks... i know it is implementet from jsf itselfe but maybe you have some ideas